# How can I save a javascript variable to database

Tags: javascript, sql, wordpress

How can I save `value1` to a database

```html
window.addEventListener("message",
function (e) {
value1= e.data;
alert (value1);
},false);
```

NB:
I am using wordpress

Comment: Anything can be saved in database but you need to add the code for the same, your php code which save the data its missing.

Comment: To post data to DB either you should have a php code, you can post data using ajax calls, but you should have a service already running up

Comment: For security concent, JavaScript doesn't connect to database directly, please use web service on the backend.

Comment: @YorkChen Not exactly. NodeJS is JavaScript and can communicate (read/write/edit/etc) with the database directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send an AJAX request to your database script:

```
    $.ajax({
    data : e.data,
    url : 'your_database_script.php'
    });
```